# Exclude a folder from redirection by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following settings for my domains, both of them are on the same hosting. Depending on which you access, you are taken to the english section or spanish.
We are adding some generic database controllers located at `_controller` but we cannot access them. On folder structure they are at the same level as /en/ and /es/.

Im using the next solution, but its not working for me, keeps jumping between the domains.

Thank you

```
RewriteEngine on

# English Language Redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.ar$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_controller/
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com.ar/en/$1 [R=301,L]

# Spanish Language Redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com.ar$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_controller/
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com.ar/es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'jumping between domains'? Is the jumping random (sometimes from en to es, sometimes from es to en)? Or does it happens always in the same direction?

Comment: ¿What do you want to do, redirecting what to what, en to es, es to en, _controller, what? That detail is missing in your question.

Comment: I want to not to be redirected when I reach `www.domain.com/_controller/file.php`

Comment: Right now, when I go to: `www.domain.com/_controller/file.php`, chrome is throwing this error: `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)`